# Stream records one by one against matching query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-warehouse

Hello everyone I hope all of u are doing well, I working on a time critical search engine and I want to know is there a way to get fetching records stream one by one against a marching query.
Like in my case I have a table of 40 million records and I want to search according to Search String  but if the search string is unique (contain rare records) or lengthy it took time to see through all the records and then return result which is time costly.
I already use indexing (ts_vector, GIN) but no help.

**Search Query:**

```
explain analyze 
Select  "SNR_SKU",
        "SNR_Title",
        "SNR_ModelNo",
        "SNR_Brand",
        "SNR_UPC",
        "SNR_Available",
        "SNR_ProductURL",
        "SNR_ImageURL",
        "SNR_Description",
        "SNR_isShow",
        "SNR_Date",
        "SNR_Category",
        "SNR_Condition",
        "SNR_SubCategory",
        "SNR_PriceBefore",
        "SNR_CustomerReviews",
        "SNR_Price"
from (
  Select *,
         similarity('apple iphone 5s 16gb',"SNR_Title") as rank
  from products_allproducts 
  Where "SNR_Title" ~ 'apple' 
    AND "SNR_Title" ~ 'iphone' 
    AND "SNR_Title" ~ '5s' 
    AND "SNR_Title" ~ '16gb' 
  ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 36 OFFSET 0
) AS rankTable;
```

```
 QUERY PLAN                                                                                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Subquery Scan on ranktable  (cost=1974848.30..1974848.32 rows=1 width=450) (actual time=16316.394..16316.395 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Limit  (cost=1974848.30..1974848.31 rows=1 width=490) (actual time=16316.392..16316.393 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=1974848.30..1974848.31 rows=1 width=490) (actual time=16316.391..16316.391 rows=1 loops=1)
               Sort Key: (similarity('apple iphone 5s 16gb'::text, (products_allproducts."SNR_Title")::text)) DESC
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..1974848.29 rows=1 width=490) (actual time=16302.006..16316.383 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 2
                     Workers Launched: 2
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on products_allproducts  (cost=0.00..1973848.19 rows=1 width=490) (actual time=11275.609..16294.657 rows=0 loops=3)
                           Filter: ((("SNR_Title")::text ~ 'apple'::text) AND (("SNR_Title")::text ~ 'iphone'::text) AND (("SNR_Title")::text ~ '5s'::text) AND (("SNR_Title")::text ~ '16gb'::text))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 6722677
Planning time: 0.902 ms
Execution time: 16462.318 ms
(13 rows)
```

Thanks.

Here is my query plan:
[image]

Comment: Indexing is one way you would deal with this.  Can you tell us more about the data you are searching, and what you are searching for?

Comment: You're asking how to improve performance of a search in a table? Post the query and the query plan. I don't know what relevance 'stream' has here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have 4 million records of different products and I want to search for a product with similar description.

Comment: Maybe show us some data if possible.  I think this would help you get an answer faster.

Comment: is that possible to partition table?

Comment: no partition table is not possible because of join overhead, I have to search query from all records @Gaj

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have attach the query plan picture above please check and let me know

Comment: is not possible to use full text search https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html

Comment: Apparently a trigram index can speed this up. Do you have a trigram index? http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2016/07/12/how-to-make-text-searches-in-postgresql-faster-with-trigram-similarity

Comment: @Gaj we already implemented trigram of Full Text search but when our query size increase from that the execution time increase